# How to get the aggregated data from mongodb to display in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

So I'm making a simple forum app and I have 2 collections:

User

```
_id:60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690
username: testuser
name: test
```

And Createpost

```
_id:60d80b1305dcc535c4bf111a
postTitle: "test post"
postText: "aaaaa"
postUsername: "testuser"
```

If I wanted to get data of testuser from User displayed on his forum post, what would be the best way to do that? This is what I've tried so far:

```
router.get('/forum', async (req,res)=>res.render('forum', {newPost: await Createpost.find().sort({ date: 'desc'}), 
postUser: Createpost.aggregate([{$lookup: { from: "User", localField: "postUsername", foreignField: "username", as: "user"}}])}));
```

Then I want to get the name field from the newly joined documents in EJS like here:

```
<% newPost.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%= newPost.postUsername %> - Name: <%= postUser.name %>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

But when I do this, it doesn't say anything, or if I only put postUser, it says "[object Object]". Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `await` in your `postUser` query. So the return of this query can be a `promise`. I edited it a bit and just made 1 query to get all the data
you needed.

```js
router.get('/forum', async (req, res) => {
    const newPosts = await Createpost.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'postUsername',
                foreignField: 'username',
                as: 'user'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$user'
        }
    ]);
    res.render('forum', {
        newPosts
    });
});
```

`newPosts` will have a value like this:

```json
[{
    "_id" : "60d80b1305dcc535c4bf111a",
    "postTitle" : "test post",
    "postText" : "aaaaa",
    "postUsername" : "testuser",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60ccb13a21d65f0c7c4c0690"),
        "username" : "testuser",
        "name" : "test"
    }
},...]
```

Ejs file should be like here:

```js
<% newPosts.forEach(newPost => { %>
    Posted by: <%= newPost.postUsername %> - Name: <%= newPost.user.name %>
    <%= newPost.postText %>
<% }%>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I tried your solution, and it shows the data from Createpost, but not the data from User. I suspect it's a problem with either the "from:" parameter or with the way I'm trying to retrieve the data with newPost.user.name, but I'm not sure. My user schema is called User.js in VS code but in mongodb it says "users", could this be a problem?

Comment: I have changed my answer. The value of `from` is the collection name in mongodb (`users`) and not the schema file name. Use `from: 'users'` instead. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hahaha, i figured that out yesterday but it took me like 5 hours... I felt so dumb, but thank you for all the help :D